# compiler error setting default value of stored property: trying to reference self

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

Why does the c1 declaration fail, but the c2 declaration works? Why can't I reference self to calculate a default value?

```
class TestView: UIView
{

    var c1 = CGPoint (x: CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds))
//error: Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> TestView' has no member 'bounds'

    var c2: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An object instance must be fully initialized before you can make references to self.  Initial values are processed within the initialization phase, before the object is fully initialized so they can't use self for their initial value.   On the other hand, a computed variable is more like a function and will only execute the closure when referenced and, at that point, the object is fully initialized.

You may want to try declaring your variable as lazy if you need the value stored and initialized with other variables of the same class:

```
     lazy var c3: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds))
```